# QGIS Cloud Interface

Tags: qgis-cloud

I would like to find out why my interface is different from the tutorial one? I am using the free plan which the tutorial is based on. How do I access the same interface or has this changed?

Here is my interface
[image]

Tutorial Interface
[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mKF5JuKRZp4&t=133s

Answer (score 1):

The YouTube tutorial references to the old QWC1 WebClient. QGIS Cloud uses QWC2 per default. If you like to use the old QWC1 client you can call it with:

`https://www.qgiscloud.com/account name/<map name>/qwc1`

Substitute the name of your map for `<map name>`.

But the support for QWC1 has finished.

Comment: The link provided is inactive. But I got the idea of what happened. Would still want to access the older interface instead of the current one despite support having stopped.

Comment: Copy the text of that link into your browser, and replace the words "map name" with the name of your map.